# VBA: set property fails to set an array element

Tags: vba

i have the following code, i use the nodes array to hold the 2 node objects inside the class

host application: access 2013

```
'class : cDependenciesTransplant
Dim nodes(0 To 1) As cNode

Property Set OCurNode(node As cNode)
    Set nodes(0) = node
    Set nodes(1) = node
    Set nodes(1) = Nothing

End Property

Property Get OCurNode()
    Set OCurNode = nodes(0)
End Property

'calling code
Public Function StructureDependencies(DepList As cDependenciesList, _
                                  Optional BOB As String = "{", _
                                  Optional EOB As String = "}" _
                                  ) As Boolean

Dim DepTrans As cDependenciesTransplant
Set DepTrans = New cDependenciesTransplant
Set DepTrans.OCurNode = DepList.FirstNode

'FirstNode :
'class: cDependenciesList
Property Get FirstNode() As cNode
    Dim node As cNode
    Set node = New cNode
    Set node.ContList = Me
    Set node.ContDep = Me.pDependency(1)
    node.nNode = 0
    Set FirstNode = node
End Property
```

when i execute and monitor the watch

```
Set nodes(0) = node
```

does nothing, nodes(0) still holds nothing but OCurNode holds the reference to the object

[image: Set nodes(0) = node SCRSHT]

```
Set nodes(1) = node
```

changes nodes(0) to hold the object

[image]
    Set nodes(1) = Nothing
changes both nodes(0) and nodes(1) to nothing

no matter what i do i can't change nodes(0)
if i change array size to 3 cells as nodes(2)
then i can address nodes(1) and nodes (2) but still nodes (0) never changes.

I guess i can work around it by not using an array to hold those 2 elements but i am really intrigued, is it a bug in VBA or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Highlighted in yellow is not yet executed. `OCurNode` that "holds the reference to the object" is probably your `Property Get`.

Comment: i know about the highlight, i will edit and post the get code

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Nodes(0) is not related to nodes(1), and OCurNode always reflects nodes(0). There is apparently some other relevant code.

Comment: Show the code that's setting the OCurNode property. Also, what is the host application and version that you're using?

Comment: ok i added more info and the "surrounding" code

Comment: This behavior is certainly mysterious. Does it happen in other host applications? Can you come up with a small but complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Is this still a problem for you or did you get an answer? I am interested in figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's because all cells in the array (0 and 1) point to the same reference.  The nodes() array is essentially a list of references - all to the same object.  When you set the node(1) equal to nothing you destroy the object so nodes(0) is also set to nothing simultaneously.

It seems like you may want to build a array of nodes() that point to different instances.  If that's what you are after, you should increment your nodes(i) array with each new node that is added (i=i+1).

```
'Refrain from using Dim in a class
'better to declare this as private
Private nodes(0 To 1) As cNode
Private i             As Integer

Property Set OCurNode(node As cNode)
    If i <= Ubound(nodes) Then
        Set nodes(i) = node
        i=i+1
    End If
End Property
```